# Loop through array to create React grid.

Tags: reactjs

So I've done the below setup before to create one big chunk of html as a string and then pass it to the render of a div using dangerouslySetInnerHTML.
The issue this time is I need to use react component elements instead of a blob of html. 
So for example where the  tags are I need to use 'react-router-dom' Link component

```
<Link to={item.path}>{item.name}</Link>
```

In the past I've used this html string.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Menu = props => {
  const sortedList = props.list.sort((a,b) => (a.name < b.name) ? -1 : (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : 0);

  const mapToAlphaGrid = () => {
    const cap = '</div>';
    const max = sortedList.length;
    let lastChar="";
    let row = '<div class="row">';
    let col = '<div class="grid-col col-4">';
    let html = row;
    let isCap = false;

    for(var i=0; i < max; i++ ){
      let item = sortedList[i];
      let char = item.name.charAt(0);

      if(char > lastChar){
        let alphaTitle = `<div class="alpha-title">${char}</div>`
        html += isCap ? cap + col + alphaTitle : col + alphaTitle;
        isCap = true;
      }

      html += `<a class="link" href=${item.path}>${item.name}</a>`;

      lastChar = char;
      if(i >= max-1){
        return html + cap + cap;
      }
    }

  }

  return(
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: mapToAlphaGrid() }} />
  )
}

export default Menu;
```

I would achieve the above using component's instead of html string ? 
Its basically a grid but each column could have multiple Link components. 
Here is how it should look based on my array of data. As you can see some columns will have 2 and three links others may have 1.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert this to JSX. You can use `reduce` to iterate through your sorted items and create a menu object where each key is the letter and the value is an array of items:

```js
class Menu extends React.Component {
  mapToAlphaGrid = () => {

    return this.props.list.sort((a, b) => a.name - b.name)
      .reduce((menu, item) => {
        if (menu[item.name.charAt(0)]) {
          // Add to existing menu item
          menu[item.name.charAt(0)].push(item)
        } else {
          // Create new menu item
          menu[item.name.charAt(0)] = [item];
        }
        return menu;
      }, {});

  };

  renderMenu = () => {
    const menuItems = this.mapToAlphaGrid();
    return Object.keys(menuItems).map(key => {
      const items = menuItems[key];
      return ( 
        <div>
          <span>{key}</span> 
          <ul> 
            {items.map(item => {
              return <li><a href={item.path}>{item.name}</a></li >
            })} 
          </ul> 
        </div>
      )
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div> 
        {this.renderMenu()} 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const list = [{
  name: 'apples',
  path: '/a'
}, {
  name: 'airplanes',
  path: '/a'
}, {
  name: 'bananas',
  path: '/b'
}, {
  name: 'car',
  path: '/c'
}, {
  name: 'crow',
  path: '/c'
}, {
  name: 'cow',
  path: '/c'
}, {
  name: 'yoyo',
  path: '/y'
}, {
  name: 'yellow',
  path: '/y'
}, {
  name: 'zebra',
  path: '/z'
}];

ReactDOM.render( <Menu list={list} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You will need to edit my snippet and replace the `<a>` tag with your `react-router` `<Link />`.